# unable to connect from phone to unbuntu hotspot

Tags: hot-spot

I have set up a hotspot in ubuntu(running 22.04) using nm-connector-editor, but I cant connect to this hotspot from any android devices while connecting a windows laptop to the same ubuntu hotspot works.

Answer (score -2):

I landed here as I was wanting to know how to automatically connect to my hotspot from my phone. I have had success connecting using the QR code, but it won't connect next time by itself. To connect via QR, I open NetworkManager and right mouse click the hotspot then select "Show Network's QR code" then on my phone under the wifi connections I select the symbol that looks like square brackets with a scanner(horizontal line) in the middle [-].

Comment: kindly understand the question asked by OP before answering anything here!